# How to append two video/webm blobs captured from MediaRecorder in javascript

Tags: javascript, blob, mediarecorder

I have two media recorders capturing two different videos of two browser tabs. As a result, i have two video/webm type blobs with their own timestamps. I want to append the second one after the first one, and then show a single video as an output. I tried using this library - https://github.com/muaz-khan/ConcatenateBlobs/blob/master/ConcatenateBlobs.js but this doesn't increase the timestamp of the second video, so both are just merged at the same timestamp.